# how to solve Server external ID not matching to pixel external ID on fb?

Tags: facebook, shopify, pixel, init

So my fb pixel is active but isn't being detected on my website ( made on shopify ). I got as a diagnostic in my events manager that:

> Server external ID not matching to pixel external ID
> You're sending the external_ID parameter for your PageView event from your server, but you're not sending the external_ID parameter for this event from your pixel. If you send external_ID for an event from your server, you must send it from your pixel as well in order for that event to be valid.

Then as a solution, they said:
**Send external_ID as part of your pixel init call.**

Now my website's source code is open and i'm just staring at it dumbly not knowing what to do.

Comment: Hi folks, I have the same issue.
Did you find any solution to this?